# Crystal Reports version Issue

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports

Hi I have developed windows app using c# to load the crystal reports dynamically from the code. In my development machine Crystal reports versions "10.5.3700.0" and "11.0.3300.0" installed. While building the app, by default 10.5.3700.0 version selected to my project while selecting the references of (CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll,CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.dll,CrystalDecisions.Shared.dll,CrystalDecisions.Web.dll) and It works fine in my Dev server. If I moved the same exe file to another server, there only 11.0.3300.0 version installed. It was throwing could not load assembly version error. How do I build my application with 11.0.3300.0 ver and make it work in other server.

Please help me out .. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the version 10.5.3700.0 from your computer and use only 11.0.3300.0 everywhere.

I had many issues like that with Crystal Report. I finally change to ITextSharp to create my PDF file. Much easier.